# Tomcat is crashing and mod_jk and Error log is flooded with Errors

Tags: java, windows, apache, tomcat, siteminder

We are running Performance load of good number Users in customer QA Environment, we are also monitoring using PERFMON and DEBUGDIAG as well to see if some dump get created. After 10 minutes of running Load, SPAgent Service is crashing and Application went down and Mod_jk is flooded with Errors -

[error] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1630): (ajp13) connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=61)

Also Error_log is flooded with -
[mpm_winnt:warn] [pid 5764:tid 4936] (OS 64)The specified network name is no longer available.  : AH00341: winnt_accept: Asynchronous AcceptEx failed.
[mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5764:tid 512] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.

In one of the Error log -

[Fri Feb 13 16:09:46.544761 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8120:tid 572] AH00455: Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) mod_jk/1.2.37 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Feb 13 16:09:46.544761 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8120:tid 572] AH00456: Server built: Aug 23 2013 00:24:10
[Fri Feb 13 16:09:46.544761 2015] [core:notice] [pid 8120:tid 572] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\CA\Agent-for-SharePoint\httpd\bin\httpd.exe -d C:/CA/Agent-for-SharePoint/httpd'
[Fri Feb 13 16:09:46.546761 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8120:tid 572] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5764
[Fri Feb 13 17:01:53.622513 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8120:tid 572] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Fri Feb 13 17:01:55.706721 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8120:tid 572] AH00430: Parent: Child process 5764 exited successfully.

Server.conf -

```
worker.ajp13.port=8009
worker.ajp13.host=localhost
worker.shutdown.port=8005

worker.ajp13.reply_timeout=3600000
worker.ajp13.retries=2

ajp13.accept_count=64
ajp13.min_spare_threads=64
ajp13.max_threads=1024

worker.ajp13.connection_pool_timeout=0

worker.ajp13.max_packet_size=16384
```

The Load of Users is 650 and about every 12 minutes the User count is around 300-330 users and SPAgent service crashes. This is much lesser to the production environment. Can anyone suggest what could be the reason.

However the main issue is SPAgent is shutting down and not responding automatically due to which they got few crashes. They manually need to start the  service in order to get it work. For that purpose we are trying to reproduce in QA Environment.

Comment: As far as I can see, all of that evidence is from the apache side ... saying that Tomcat has crashed / exitted.  Nothing from the Tomcat side to say why.  I don't see how we can help you unless you provide the latter evidence.

Comment: Thanks Stephen for Reply. What exactly you need, I can provide it you.

Comment: Well you should start by looking at the Tomcat logs.

Comment: If I see mod_jk.log, it is showing [Fri Feb 13 16:09:33.095 2015] [2388:3728] [error] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1630): (ajp13) connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=61)
[Fri Feb 13 16:09:34.199 2015] [2388:3728] [error] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1630): (ajp13) connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=61)
[Fri Feb 13 16:09:34.199 2015] [2388:3728] [error] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2643): (ajp13) connecting to tomcat failed.

Comment: Nothing else is there in this mod_jk except the above errors which I posted

Comment: You still looking in / posting the Apache Httpd logs.  Mod_jk is an Apache Httpd module. Look in the Tomcat logs.

Comment: There is nothing any errors reported in tomcat logs. Do you want to see any config files. It is happening after 10-15 mins of running the load and mod_jk is flooded with those errors

Comment: Also by adding following in httpd.conf, we got rid of Accept_Ex errors coming in Error log - AcceptFilter https none 
AcceptFilter http none 
EnableSendfile Off 
EnableMMAP off
But actual issue is not resolved..

Comment: Is Tomcat actually crashing?  If it is, you have to find out why.   Futzing around with the Apache httpd configs is ... missing the point.  Completely.